How to use python to extract highlighted text and the annotations associated with that highlighted text?
As an example lets say I have a pdf and there is highlighted text that says "is on sales for $100" and there is a comment attached to that highlighted text that says "replace with $99".
What I want to do in an ideal world either into a dataframe, table, or JSON is be able to tie the highlighted text the comment was about to the actual comment added to the pdf.



Highlighted Text
Comment




is on sales for $100
replace with $99


Cell 3
Cell 4



    import pymupdf

doc = pymupdf.open("demo.pdf")
print("Number of pages:", doc.page_count)  # Check the number of pages

for i in range(doc.page_count):
    page = doc[i]
    annotations = list(page.annots())  # Convert the generator to a list
    if annotations:  # Check if there are any annotations
        print(f"Page {i+1} has {len(annotations)} annotations:")
        for annot in annotations:
            print(annot.info)  # Print detailed annotation info
    else:
        print(f"Page {i+1} has no annotations.")

doc.close()  # Good practice to close the document

And the result:
Number of pages: 12
Page 1 has 2 annotations:
{'content': 'replace with excitment', 'name': '', 'title': '', 'creationDate': '', 'modDate': '', 'subject': '', 'id': ''}
{'content': 'Remove "rapid progress" from this sentence', 'name': '', 'title': '', 'creationDate': '', 'modDate': '', 'subject': '', 'id': ''}
Page 2 has no annotations.
Page 3 has no annotations.
Page 4 has 1 annotations:
{'content': 'replace with initial idea generation', 'name': '', 'title': '', 'creationDate': '', 'modDate': '', 'subject': '', 'id': ''}
Page 5 has no annotations.
Page 6 has no annotations.
Page 7 has no annotations.
Page 8 has no annotations.
Page 9 has no annotations.
Page 10 has no annotations.
Page 11 has no annotations.
Page 12 has no annotations.

But it only shows the comments added not the actual text that is highlighted and what the comment is pointing too.

Comment objects in a PDF have a pointer to the targeted text.  Have you examined the properties of the comment objects you get back?

@TimRoberts I added additional information above. probably something wrong with my code but I only see the comments content not the targeted text.

Here is what I ended up using:
import pymupdf
from tabulate import tabulate

doc = pymupdf.open("demo.pdf")
print("Number of pages:", doc.page_count)  # Check the number of pages

table_data = []  # Initialize a list to store the table data

for i in range(doc.page_count):
    page = doc[i]
    annotations = list(page.annots())  # Convert the generator to a list
    if annotations:  # Check if there are any annotations
        print(f"Page {i+1} has {len(annotations)} annotations:")
        for annot in annotations:
            if annot.type[1] == "Highlight":  # Check if it's a highlight annotation
                # Get the coordinates of the highlighted area
                rect = annot.rect
                # Extract the highlighted text using the 'text' option for get_text()
                highlighted_text = page.get_text(clip=rect, option = "text") 
                # Extract content from annot.info (assuming it's a JSON-like string)
                content = annot.info.get("content", "") # Use .get() to handle cases where 'content' might be missing
                # Append the data as a row to the table_data list
                table_data.append([i+1, highlighted_text, content]) 

    else:
        print(f"Page {i+1} has no annotations.")

doc.close()  # Good practice to close the document

# Create a table using tabulate
table = tabulate(table_data, headers=["Page", "Highlighted Text", "Content"], tablefmt="grid")
print(table)

